# Integral of Natural Logarithm

Tags: logarithms, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I been trying to solve the following problem:

[image: problem]

When I solve it myself, depending on which technique I use, I end up finding either

[image: answer1] or [image: answer2]]

Yet both results are completely different. I even tried typing it on a calculator, and this is what I get.

[image: calculator]

Can someone please explain how one can proceed to go from the second to last step to the last step, because both of these last steps give different results?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are actually the same. This is because

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{3\ln(|5x + 5|)}{5} + C & = \frac{3\ln(|5(x + 1)|)}{5} + C \\
& = \frac{3(\ln(|x + 1|) + \ln(5))}{5} + C \\
& = \frac{3\ln(|x + 1|)}{5} + \frac{3\ln(5)}{5} + C \\
& = \frac{3\ln(|x + 1|)}{5} + C_2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

where $C_2 = \frac{3\ln(5)}{5} + C$ is also an arbitrary constant since $C$ is an arbitrary constant. In other words, you just have another constant to include in the value of the arbitrary constant $C$ in the last step.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I didn't think at first that the constant could be different in both cases.

Comment: @TomLamensia You're welcome. As the constant is arbitrary, until it's specified, e.g., by an initial condition, it can be anything. With an initial condition, e.g., the integral is $0$ at $x = 0$, then in your case you would get $\frac{3\ln(|5x + 5|)}{5} + C = \frac{3\ln(5)}{5} + C = 0 \implies C = -\frac{3\ln(5)}{5}$. In the second case, you would get $\frac{3\ln(|x + 1|)}{5} + C = \frac{3\ln(1)}{5} + C = 0 \implies C = 0$. As you can see, the second constant would be different, due to the addition of $\frac{3\ln(5)}{5}$ of the first constant. I hope this example helps you to understand.